# Force SSL and WWW in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, web

I have searched high and low for a way to force SSL and www. but none of the many solutions I have found have worked. Currently I'm trying this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

- domain.co.uk -> https:/ /www.domain.co.uk
- www.domain.co.uk -> https:/ /domain.co.uk
- https:/ /domain.co.uk -> https:/ /domain.co.uk with SSL error

(The spaces are due to me being too new to post more than 2 links).

Is there a way to do this? After trying at least 10 different examples I'm surprised that they all end up failing on the last one.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are specifying the HTTP host but missing HTTPS host in your conditions. Like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this has the same problem; https:/ /domain.co.uk doesn't redirect to https:/ /www.domain.co.uk, just gives the SSL warning page still.